# Many to Many Ajax Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel

I have this code.

```
public function items( $subcategory_id ){

    $items = $this->ajax->items( $subcategory_id );

    return Response::json([
            'success' => 'true',
            'items' => $items
        ]);
}
```

And the output is:
[image]

As you can see the unit_id reference to many to many and you can't manipulate it to get the name of the unit_id in javascript. Do I need to loop it and create my own array or is there a function to do it.
Here is my repository code.

```
public function items( $subcategory_id ){

    $this->modelName = new Subcategory();
    return $this->modelName->find( $subcategory_id )->items;
}
```

My Model

```
    namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Subcategory extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'subcategories';
    protected $fillable = [
        'qty', 'desc', 'unit_price', 'ext_price'
    ];
    public function items(){

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Item', 'item_subcategory', 'subcategory_id', 'item_id')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

Comment: What you need to do is use eager loading. I don't however understand what your models and relations are. Post your models code.

Comment: public function items(){

     return $this->belongsToMany('App\Item', 'item_subcategory', 'subcategory_id', 'item_id')->withTimestamps();
    }

Comment: What json structure you want to send to javascript?

Comment: I already updated the model. I just want to change the unit_id to a name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use eager loading. This will fetch the a specific `Subcategory` with its related `Items` and `Units` related to those items:

```
Subcategory::where('id', $subcategoryId)->with('items.unit')->get();
```